# Aligning table row

Tags: html, css, database-design, html-table, rows

I have this table, and what I want to do is align the last row with the subjunits.

Is it possible? If so, how do I do it?

I tried using this, but it's not working. I added many `<td>` to align it, but I think there is a better way. Please help me out.

My code:

```
<table class="table table-dark table-hover col-lg-6" id="subjects" name="subjects">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Proffesor</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Classroom</th>
        <th>Time in</th>
        <th>Time out</th>
        <th>Units</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php
    $q1 ="select * from subjects";
    $ex1 = mysqli_query($conn,$q1);
    $q2 = "SELECT sum(units) AS units from subj_enrolled where studid= '1512345678' "; 
    $ex2=mysqli_query($conn,$q2);
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex2);
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($ex1);
    if ($check > 0){
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex1)) {?>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $row['subjcode'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['subjtitle'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['subjstatus'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['profid'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['section'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['classroom'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['time_in'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['time_out'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['subjunits'];?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <?php }?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "Total units: "; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $fetch['units'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and use the below code:

```
<td colspan="8"> <?php echo $fetch['units'];?></td>
```